# fopen fails when file exists

Tags: c, linux, fopen, file-permissions

I have the following snippet of code running inside a massive Linux daemon.
I'm trying to debug to a log file, but when the log file exists, the `fopen` fails

```
if ( ( debugFILE = fopen( "/home/lala/debug.log", "a" ) ) == NULL )
{
    perror("error: ");
}
```

The error I get is:  "Permission denied".

This is a the output of ls of the specific file:

```
----rw---- 1 lala lala 0 Mar 11 18:26 debug.log
```

First, why the file was created in the firstplace with these permissions.
Second, why the fopen succeeds when creating, but not when opening ?

Comment: What is your `umask -S` for the director?

Comment: @chrisaycock u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `fopen` creates files with permission `0666` modified by the process's `umask`.

So if you do not manually change the files permissions within your program or after your program has finished.

The process will most likely have a wrong umask.

Do you set the `umask` within your programm or within the context of the calling process? Your `umask -S` output actually looks fine (looks like umask `002`).

Answer (score 4):

The "a" option will always create a file if it doesn't exist, and if successful return a valid pointer. It's created according to the umask setting of the process - and in your case the process is creating a file without proper permissions, hence the next time `fopen` fails. If you don't want to mess with the umask, just call this before and after the `fopen`:

```
chmod("/home/lala/debug.log", 0644);
```

It's fine to call `chmod` in this way if the file doesn't exist, it'll just do nothing (except for setting `errno` appropriately).